# Set shared.loader with MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse

Is there a way to set the shared.loader catalina.properties variable with the MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER value?

I want to add the library dependencies of a maven eclipse project to that variable. I can add a VM argument to my tomcat launch configuration which can contain a value that is usable within the catalina.properties (similar to -Dcatalina.home=..) but i don't know how to get a usable variable from the org.maven.ide.eclipse.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH Library Container or export it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I now use a eclipse maven task that executes dependency:dependency-copy for my project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/mavendependencies</outputDirectory>
        <excludeArtifactIds>jsp-api,servlet-api</excludeArtifactIds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I set the workspace.dir property within my server launch configuration like this:

```
 -Dworkspace.dir=${workspace_loc}
```

My shared.loader within catalina.properties looks now like this:

```
shared.loader=${workspace.dir}/project/target/classes,${workspace.dir}/project/target/mavendependencies/*.jar,${catalina.base}/shared/classes,${catalina.base}/shared/lib/*.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to overwrite the *catalina.properties* file location using the *catalina.config* property. In this case no catalina.properties file that has been generated by eclipse must be touched and the shared classloader can be modified by creating a custom file in your project.

```
-Dcatalina.config=file://${workspace_loc}/projectA/projectA-config/src/main/eclipse-conf/catalina.properties
```